# The Gibbsian Ensemble and Hamiltonian

Tags: statistical-mechanics

In my book it states that the equations of motion are given as [image]

It also says that these will tell us how a representative point moves in phase space as time evolves. We also assume that the Hamiltonian does not depend on any time derivative of p and q and according to the equations above it is invariant under time reversal and it determines the motion of a representative point for all times, when the position of the representative point is given at any time. It also follows immediately from these observations that the locus of a representative point is either a simple closed curve or a curve that never intersects itself and the loci of two distinct representative points never intersect.

My questions are what exactly is a locus and how do we draw it? Are we able to look at any hamiltonian of any case and though these equations draw a locus?

Comment: This is a brief restatement of things that one normally learns in classical/theoretical mechanics course. [Goldstein](https://www.abebooks.fr/Classical-Mechanics-Herbert-Goldstein-Charles-Poole/31086866538/bd?cm_mmc=ggl-_-FR_Shopp_TextbookStandard-_-naa-_-naa&gclid=CjwKCAjw8JKbBhBYEiwAs3sxN4DBsAIsIHaMY8BNpsCaPZ-YnAPyc6bxCQR-Pyed9a_z_h7_fzD1BxoCBLYQAvD_BwE) is a good book, but there are many more obviously.

Answer (score 0):

The locus is the trajectory of a system of $N$ particles in phase space. The phase space is the space defined by the position and momenta vectors of the particles. For point particles this is a space with $6N$ dimensions. The trajectory of the system is a line in this space that traces the positions and momenta of all particles.

The space has such high dimensionality that it cannot be shown graphically for practical systems. For demonstration purposes consider a harmonic oscillator in one dimension. In this case the dimensionality of space is 2 (one position plus one momentum vector). The energy of the oscillator is
$$
  E = \frac{m p^2}{2} + k\frac{x^2}{2}
$$
At fixed $E$ this defines an *ellipse* in space $(p,x)$,  a closed locus of states in phase space as the oscillator moves in real space. Use this example to visualize the more general case.